# .cpan/Metadata:how to edit to reinstall a model

Tags: perl, cpan

I use cpan to install `Carton`. When I run this command first, the output is `URL can't found`. When I run this command second, the output is follows:

```
Going to read '/home/hengaini/.cpan/Metadata'
Warning: Cannot install Carton, don't know what it is.
Try the command
    i /Carton/
to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

I think the file `/home/hengaini/.cpan/Metadata` can edit manual or by some tool to go back the first enrionment.
  What's the problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you show us the complete output of the `cpan` command, we might be able to help better.

In this case, I'd just delete everything in the *.cpan* directly and try again. `cpan` will fetch everything it needs.